# exclude lines from SUM(1) mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have multiple tables :

m_foldercommittee :

| id_folder | id_committe | opinion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |

m_folder :

| id_folder | id_committe |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

m_schedule :

| id_schedule | type_schedule | id_folder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

m_committee :

| id_committee | date_committee |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

for now, the query looks like this :

```
select c.date_committee,
    sum(1) as total,
    sum(if(fc.opinion= 1 , 1, 0)) as nb_folder,
    sum(if(fc.opinion= 2 , 1, 0)) as nb_folder_favorable,
    sum(if(fc.opinion= 3 , 1, 0)) as nb_folder_principe,
from m_foldercommittee fc
    INNER JOIN m_committee c ON c.id_committee = fc.id_committee
    INNER JOIN m_folder mf ON mf.id_folder = fc.id_folder
where EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
             FROM m_schedule sch 
             WHERE sch.type_schedule = 1 
             AND sch.id_folder = fc.id_folder  
             AND ((sch.beginning_date >= '2022-08-25' AND sch.ending_date <= '2023-09-25')
               OR (sch.beginning_date <  '2022-08-25' AND sch.ending_date >= '2022-08-25')
               OR (sch.beginning_date <= '2023-09-25' AND sch.ending_date >= '2023-09-25')
             ))
group by fc.id_committee
```

and returns something like this :

| date_committe | total | nb_folder | nb_folder_favorable | nb_folder_principe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-25 | 13 | 12 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-09-15 | 24 | 20 | 4 | 0 |
| 2023-09-25 | 91 | 88 | 3 | 0 |

what I want is to insert a new column that is the sum of type_schedule = 1 but I don't want to be part of the sum(1).

here is what I wrote so far :

```
select c.date_committee,
    sum(1) as total,
    sum(if(sch.type_schedule= 1 , 1, 0)) as nb_beverage,
    sum(if(fc.opinion= 1 , 1, 0)) as nb_folder,
    sum(if(fc.opinion= 2 , 1, 0)) as nb_folder_favorable,
    sum(if(fc.opinion= 3 , 1, 0)) as nb_folder_principe,
from m_foldercommittee fc
    INNER JOIN m_committee c ON c.id_committee = fc.id_committee
    INNER JOIN m_folder mf ON mf.id_folder = fc.id_folder
    INNER JOIN m_schedule sch ON sch.id_folder = fc.id_folder
where EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
             FROM m_schedule sch 
             WHERE sch.type_schedule = 1 and sch.id_folder = fc.id_folder  
             AND ((sch.beginning_date >= '2022-08-25' AND sch.ending_date <= '2023-09-25')
               OR (sch.beginning_date <  '2022-08-25' AND sch.ending_date >= '2022-08-25')
               OR (sch.beginning_date <= '2023-09-25' AND sch.ending_date >= '2023-09-25')
             ))
group by fc.id_committee
```

it works but the problem is that the second version query return values that are totally different of the first version query. how to exclude the results of`sum(if(sch.type_schedule= 1 , 1, 0)) as nb_beverage` from the sum(1), so the new version query returns the exact sames results as the first one but with a new column *nb_beverage* ?

Comment: Not quite following the last bit, but if you want SUM(1) to be the difference between nb_beverages and the total can't you just do the same conditional statement but with sch.type_schedule <> 1?

Comment: If you are grouping by `id_committee` and your select has the column `date_committee` that value is a non predictable one. If you want the dates to be the aggregate factor you should be using `group by c.date_committee`. This might not be your problem. Just wanted you to know that it makes no sense.

Comment: Try to GROUP BY in subqueries before joining.

Comment: @Error_2646 I may have not be clear but what I want is the two queries to have the exact same result but with a new column. what I wrote is changing every values from other colums, which I do not want. how would yoy do sch.type_schedule <> 1? I don't get it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos group by id_committee and date_committee would result the same.

Comment: @jarlh I have already try this, maybe the wrong way. I will try again, thank you.

Comment: Change `SUM(1)` to be `SUM(IF(condition_to_exclude, 0, 1))`

Comment: Of course, ID is likely the primary key, there are no duplicates. Id with anything in the group by would result in the same data. Again, grouping by id and having a data that might have duplicates in the select statement generates unpredictable results for the column (in this case date)

Comment: Found a useful article that explains what I'm trying to say, please read it. https://www.dataquest.io/blog/sql-tutorial-selecting-ungrouped-columns-without-aggregate-functions/

Comment: @JorgeCampos hi, thank you for the article.

Comment: @jarlh I managed to get the results I wanted by using a subquery, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what worked using subquery as suggested in the comments by @jarlh. I hope this will be usefull :

```
select c.date_committee,
    sum(1) as total,
    IFNULL(sum(beverage.nb_beverage),0) as nb_bevarge,
    sum(if(fc.opinion= 1 , 1, 0)) as nb_folder,
    sum(if(fc.opinion= 2 , 1, 0)) as nb_folder_favorable,
    sum(if(fc.opinion= 3 , 1, 0)) as nb_folder_principe,
from m_foldercommittee fc
    INNER JOIN m_committee c ON c.id_committee = fc.id_committee
    INNER JOIN m_folder mf ON mf.id_folder = fc.id_folder
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT count(sch2.id_schedule) as nb_beverage, fc2.id_committee as id_committee, fc2.id_folder as id_folder FROM m_schedule sch2
        INNER JOIN m_foldercommittee fc2 on sch2.id_folder=fc2.id_folder
        WHERE sch2.type_schedule=5
        GROUP BY id_committee, id_folder) beverage ON beverage.id_committee = fc.id_committee and beverage.id_folder = fc.id_folder
where EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
             FROM m_schedule sch 
             WHERE sch.type_schedule = 1 and sch.id_folder = fc.id_folder  
             AND ((sch.beginning_date >= '2022-08-25' AND sch.ending_date <= '2023-09-25')
               OR (sch.beginning_date <  '2022-08-25' AND sch.ending_date >= '2022-08-25')
               OR (sch.beginning_date <= '2023-09-25' AND sch.ending_date >= '2023-09-25')
             ))
group by fc.id_committee
```

Comment: Please read: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20question,on%20a%20Stack%20Exchange%20site.), and mark it as **answered**